# symfony2 error 500 after migration

Tags: symfony

I'm getting a 500 error on almost every route after migrating my web to a online server.
I developed my site under xampp without problems (site worked on dev and prod)

I placed the site under a subdomain (http://escritorio.gruposcout45.org.uy) pointing to the web folder of my project.

This is my error log:

```
[2012-06-14 10:24:26] security.DEBUG: Read SecurityContext from the session [] []
[2012-06-14 10:24:26] security.DEBUG: Reloading user from user provider. [] []
[2012-06-14 10:24:26] security.DEBUG: Username "admin" was reloaded from user provider. [] []
[2012-06-14 10:24:26] request.INFO: Matched route "socio" (parameters: "_controller": "Caro\SociosBundle\Controller\SocioController::indexAction", "_route": "socio") [] []
[2012-06-14 10:24:26] request.CRITICAL: Twig_Error_Syntax: The function "knp_menu_render" does not exist in "::base.html.twig" (uncaught exception) at /home/neuronas/public_html/gruposcout45.org.uy/escritorio/vendor/twig/lib/Twig/Node/Expression/Function.php line 28 [] []
[2012-06-14 10:24:26] security.DEBUG: Write SecurityContext in the session [] []
```

And my autoloader:

```
$loader->registerNamespaces(array(
   'Symfony'          => array(__DIR__.'/../vendor/symfony/src', __DIR__.'/../vendor/bundles'),
    'Sensio'           => __DIR__.'/../vendor/bundles',
    'JMS'              => __DIR__.'/../vendor/bundles',
    'Doctrine\\Common' => __DIR__.'/../vendor/doctrine-common/lib',
    'Doctrine\\DBAL'   => __DIR__.'/../vendor/doctrine-dbal/lib',
    'Doctrine'         => __DIR__.'/../vendor/doctrine/lib',
    'Monolog'          => __DIR__.'/../vendor/monolog/src',
    'Assetic'          => __DIR__.'/../vendor/assetic/src',
    'Metadata'         => __DIR__.'/../vendor/metadata/src',
    'Knp\\Component'   => __DIR__.'/../vendor/knp-components/src',
    'Knp\\Bundle'      => __DIR__.'/../vendor/bundles',
    'Knp\Menu'   => __DIR__.'/../vendor/KnpMenu/src',
));
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The routing is loaded from apps/config/routing.yml. Can you post the contents of that file?

Answer (score 2):

I didn't put this in my AppKernel:

```
new Knp\Bundle\MenuBundle\KnpMenuBundle(),
new Knp\Bundle\PaginatorBundle\KnpPaginatorBundle(),
```

Once I added this lines and cleared the cache everything worked fine.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed your vendors correctly ? You have a problem with Knp\Menu twig functions.